# PHP no detecta php_interbase.dll, php_pdo_firebird.dll y sí existen en mi carpeta c:\xampp\php\ext ¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Tags: php, xampp, firebird

Tengo el siguiente problema y llevo varios días con él.
Estoy usando **php 7.3.22** y **firebird 2.5** y al usar **phpinfo()** NO MUESTRA NADA de **Interbase**

**interbase.dll** y **php_pdo_firebird.dll** y ya están descomentados en el **php.ini** lo siguiente:

**extension=interbase** y **extension=pdo_firebird**

al abrir **error.log** manda lo siguiente

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'interbase' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\interbase (No se puede
> encontrar el módulo especificado.),
> C:\xampp\php\ext\php_interbase.dll (%1 no es una aplicación Win32
> válida.)) in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_firebird (No se puede
> encontrar el módulo especificado.),
> C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (%1 no es una aplicación
> Win32 válida.)) in Unknown on line 0

Ya revise y el **fbclient.dll** de la carpeta de firebird ya está em el raíz de la carpeta de mi php

Simplemente no detecta dichos DLL's que sí existen.
Espero me puedan ayudar. de antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrias indicar qué pasos seguiste para la instalación: archivos descargados y de dónde, si hiciste cambios en `php.ini` y cuáles, qué configuración tienes, sistema operativo y versión, etc?

Comment: Claro, estoy usando xampp 7.3.22 y en el php.ini hice esto ;
;extension=imap
extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci                                                                                                      Quite los ; de los dll indicados estoy trabajando en un servidor Windows Server 2008

Comment: se que es algo ya de tiempo pasado, pero estoy justo lidiando con ese problema, pudiste resolverlo ?